# Incremental loading of GridView with MVVMCross in WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime, mvvmcross

I'm struggling to come with a way to implement incremental loading of GridView when using WinRT.

The documentation only specifies one method for doing incremental loading in WinRT - binding to a collection that implements ISupportIncrementalLoading. However, this interface does not exist in portable class library.

I am wondering if it's possible to keep viewmodels in a core PCL and still implement incremental loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an interface doesn't exist in the pcl profiles, then one way forwards is to copy the interface into pcl and to then use a ValueConverter to wrap and adapt the interface into it's native equivalent.

This works well for small interfaces - it's similar to how MvvmCross makes `IValueConverter` itself into a portable interface.

So, yes it's possible to implement the ViewModel in PCL and for the native UI to then use a non-portable interface via an adapter.

However, the above process can be a bit tedious to do if you need to marshall/adapt a larger object - e.g. if you need to marshall `ISupportIncrementalLoading`, plus also other interfaces like `IEnumerable`, `ICollection`, etc...

In this case, it may be easier to move that 'ViewModel' out into non-PCL code.

Generally I would do this by just putting the collection into non-PCL code - e.g. by:

1. declaring portable `IMyIncrementalCollectionFactory` and `IMyIncrementalCollection<T>` interfaces something like:

   ```
   public interface IMyIncrementalCollectionFactory
   {
       IMyIncrementalCollection<T> Create();
   }

   public interface IMyIncrementalCollection<T>
   {
       event EventHandler<RequireMore<T>> OnRequireMore;
       void SetHasMore(bool value);
   }
   ```
2. implementing `IMyIncrementalCollection<T>` in WinRT using a collection class which maps `LoadMoreItemsAsync<T>` calls into `OnRequireMore` events
3. implementing `IMyIncrementalCollectionFactory` in WinRT using a class which returns instances of the above collection
4. writing my page-level ViewModel to use `IMyIncrementalCollectionFactory` to create the collection.

This same process would me to keep the 'load more' logic itself in the shared code.